# Retrieve the Oldest Value in Archer

Tags: archer, rsa-archer-grc

Is there an opposite function in Archer for MostRecentValue? I wanted to get the very first record in a Related Records Field in a calculated text field. What should I use?

Answer (score 2):

No there isn't a built-in function for this... e.g. OldValue().  But, here's something that should work:

---

### Copy and save the first related record, when it is created:

- Create a simple text field (not a calculated field) for storing the first record.  Call it something like "FirstDate"
- Create an `Action` that is triggered whenever the Related Record Field (the one you care about)'s value changes:

  - The action should check to see if the `FirstDate` field is EMPTY.
  - If it **IS** empty, then the action should set it to the value in the Related Record Field
  - If it **IS NOT** empty, it should end and do nothing
- You can then always retrieve the first "earliest" record from the `FirstDate` field.

Comment: how do we perform this: "If it IS empty, then the action should set it to the value in the Related Record Field"

Comment: if `FirstDate = "" or FirstDate = null then FirstDate = MyRelatedRecordField`